# How to only change color of the last character in a javafx TextField

Tags: java, javafx, colors, textfield

I am trying to make a typing game, I created a text field for user input and am trying to make the game so that the last char of the textfield is red if it doesn't match the corresponding char in the words to be typed. Below is what I have so far along with the current types of relevant nodes.

```java
Label wordsToType = new Label();
TextField userInput = new TextField();
StringBuilder wordsTyped = new StringBuilder();
TextField lastChar = new TextField();

userInput.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
    wordsTyped.append(userInput.getText()); // words typed is a string builder of what is in userInput

    if (wordsTyped.toString().charAt(wordsTyped.length() - 1) - wordsToType.getText().charAt(wordsTyped.length() - 1) != 0) {
        lastChar.setText(e.getText());
        lastChar.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-font-size: 16px;");
        wordsTyped.setLength(wordsTyped.length() - 1); // deletes last char from wordsTyped
        userInput.setText(wordsTyped.toString() + lastChar.getText());
        userInput.end();
    }
    wordsTyped.delete(0, wordsTyped.length());
});
```

Comment: Both `TextField` and `TextArea` can only have one style for all the text, at least with how their default skins are implemented. To have text with multiple styles you might want to look into using `TextFlow` plus multiple `Text` nodes. There's also a library out there called _RichTextFX_ which may provide what you want.

Comment: That said, selected text in a text field has a different style from other text in the field, and the style of both is configurable independently by css. Perhaps you could select the last character in the field.  It may help you or may not.

Comment: @Slaw I added a sample code for `RichTextFX`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) to highlight input texts with different styles. Here is a sample code:

**Java:**

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleClassedTextField;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyledTextField;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.model.StyleSpans;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.model.StyleSpansBuilder;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class HighlightedTextFieldExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StyledTextField<Collection<String>, Collection<String>> textField = new StyleClassedTextField();
        textField.lengthProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue > 0) {
                StyleSpans<Collection<String>> styleSpans = new StyleSpansBuilder<Collection<String>>()
                        .add(Collections.emptyList(), newValue - 1) // no style (leading characters)
                        .add(Collections.singleton("last-character"), 1) // add a style class for the last character
                        .create();
                textField.setStyleSpans(0, styleSpans);
            }
        });
        textField.setPrefWidth(400);

        Scene scene = new Scene(textField);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(HighlightedTextFieldExample.class.getResource("highlighting.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Last Character Highlighting Example");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**CSS Style File (`highlighter.css`):**

```css
.last-character {
    -fx-fill: red;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]